# How to add extra object to tasty pie return json in python django

Tags: python, django, tastypie

In Django project i get two objects when i receive the JSON response

`data.meta` and `data.objects`

This is my Resource

```
class MyResource(ModelResource):
    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.data["absolute_url"] = bundle.obj.get_absolute_url()
        bundle.data['myfields'] = MyDataFields
        return bundle
    class Meta:

        queryset = MyData.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'weather'
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
        ordering = MyDataFields
```

now i want to other field in json like

`data.myfields`

but if i do the above way then that field is added to every object like

`data.objects.myfields`

how can i do `data.myfields`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is by overriding Tastypie ModelResource's `get_list` method.

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

...

class MyResource(ModelResource):

    ...

    def get_list(self, request, **kwargs):
        resp = super(MyResource, self).get_list(request, **kwargs)

        data = json.loads(resp.content)

        data['myfields'] = MyDataFields

        data = json.dumps(data)

        return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json', status=200)
```

Answer (score 20):

a better approach IMHO would be to use [alter_list_data_to_serialize](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html?#Resource.alter_list_data_to_serialize), the function made to override/add fields to the data before making the response:

```
    def alter_list_data_to_serialize(self, request, data):
        data['meta']['current_time'] = datetime.strftime(datetime.utcnow(), "%Y/%m/%d") 
        return data
```

This way you don't override all the mimetype/status code for all calls and it's cleaner.

Comment: Thanks ! I used that to add bounding box from a GeoDjango query: `data['extent'] = self._meta.queryset.extent()`

Comment: Thanks a lot this saved me lot of time and effort!